# MeteorJS highload applications

Tags: node.js, meteor

Do these already exist? Does anyone have any real experience with highload applications using the meteor.js framework? Are there any such known services or applications or designs based on this technolody?

Comment: Currently it's a known problem that Meteor doesn't scale particularly well on the server-side. But this is currently the team's highest priority, and it sounds like solutions should be in place within the next few months.

Comment: I hope that my current project ends up testing the limits of whatever the meteor.js framework and hosting provides. :P

Comment: I would not rely on hosting at meteor.com. It is a free service for demo purposes. The earlier you move somewhere else, like Heroku, the easier your production rollout will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update apr 4, 2013: since we were not able to scale on Heroku due to Meteor's session affinity, we moved to EC2 with ELB. We've tested this with about 800 concurrent users, which is 4x what we were getting with Heroku. FMI: [1] http://www.ripariandata.com/blog/creating-an-aws-elastic-load-balancer

update jan 18, 2013: we've done some load testing on our app using blitz.io. On a single heroku Dyno, with a MongoHQ back end, we are able to get to 35 concurrent operations before timeouts start exceeding 1 second. We able able to get to 180 concurrent operations before the Dyno dies and needs a restart. This was against our most complex query using a five field compound index, returning between 10-30 documents, and randomly using a skip value of 0-30 (to simulate paging).

Currently, increasing the number of dynos had no substantial increase in performance. We are investigating the bottlenecks and will report back our findings.

Comment: Interesting figures, thanks a lot for sharing them! BTW, how did you manage to run meteor app on more than one dyno? I tried and failed to get it working on more than one...

Comment: The Perftesting we did had no session state or affinity, so it could run on multiple dynos. Our real app requires session affinity, which we have not found a way to do on Heroku. It might be possible via SSL affinity but we haven't tried it yet.